# DTD Prohibited in XML Document C# Exception with DtdProcessing set to DtdProcessing.Parse

Tags: c#, xslt, xml-parsing, dtd, xslcompiledtransform

I am trying to convert an XML document to another by using `XslCompiledTransform`. But I am getting an exception with the following error message:

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

I already set the `DtdProcessing` property on `XmlReaderSettings` to `Parse`.
However, I am still encountering the same exception with the same error message.

My sample code:

```cs
 XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
            XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD };
            xmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
            xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
            using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(_tesseractSettings.GetXSLTFilePath(), xmlReaderSettings))
            {
                xslt.Load(_tesseractSettings.GetXSLTFilePath());
                xslt.Transform(inputFile, outputFile);
            }
```

ValidationCallBack:

```
private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(someTxtFilePath, e.Message);
    }
```

If it is relevant here is the document type declarations.

Input XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "/W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional/EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

XSLT file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:htm="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

I have also tried setting DtdProcessing to DtdProcessing.Ignore and the same exception occurs. I have also tried removing the Document Type declaration element before the transformation. When I do this I no longer get the exception, however the transformation doesn't give me the output I expect. I know the issue isn't with the xslt file because the transformation still works on Oxygen or any online tester.

I have been researching the internet but with no avail.
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Don't you also need to set `ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD` ?

Comment: Does the XML input use a DTD? Or the XSLT? Or both?

Comment: @tmakita I added this, however it still gives me the same exception. I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The XML input uses a DTD, I don't believe the XSLT does but I included the xslt stylesheet tag in the question I don't know if that means it uses DTD.

Answer (score 2):

DTD which stands for `Document Type Definition`.The purpose of a DTD is to define the structure and the legal elements and attributes of an XML document. However it is occasionally exploited by hackers to perform something known as [XXE (XML External Entity) attacks](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/xxe-xml-external-entity-attacks/).

So Microsoft basically provides three options for Dtd Processing to avoid such attacks:

- Parse: Allows parsing of DTD content inside of xml file by the xml reader. However we need to set also the validation type and validation callback to report any errors/warnings.

Inline is an example from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing?view=netcore-3.1):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;

public class Sample {

    public static void Main() {

    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler (ValidationCallBack);

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("itemDTD.xml", settings);

    // Parse the file.
    while (reader.Read());
  }

  // Display any validation errors.
  private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {
     Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
  }
}
```

- Prohibit: Also the default value of DtdProcessing. Throws an exception when xml reader encounters any DTD content in xml file.
- Ignore: It simply instructs the xml reader to ignore any dtd content inside of xml file and process it. As a result the output is ripped of any dtd content if present. Thus results in loss of data.

Comment: I added the ValidationType and set it to ValidationType.DTD. However, I am still encountering the same exception. I also edited the original question and added more relevant information.

Comment: Can you add in the validation callback as well and check. Also can you confirm that you are getting the error at the line "XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(_tesseractSettings.GetXSLTFilePath(), new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD})" or somewhere else?

Comment: First off, thank you for the help and the quick responses. This is an issue I have been stuck on over a week. I have added the validation callback function, however it isn't being called when the error occurs. The error is also occurring at the line "xslt.Transform(inputFile, outputFile);".

Comment: If that is the case than we are applying fix at the wrong place then. Can you tell us what the inputFile parameter contains. If it is a path to an XML file, can you read it via an Xmlreader with aforementioned Xmlreader settings and check again

Comment: This provided me with errors that led to some progress. In the context of my problem technically I don't need the document declaration so I removed it from the input XML document before transforming it. My current problem is the transformation isn't working as expected. I know the problem doesn't lie with my xsl because in Oxygen the transformation works as expected. When I do the transformation with C# it gives me a completely different output, but it is at least transforming the XML now. I am new to stack overflow, should I start a new question and share the link?

Comment: Yeah, even I think a new question would be a good approach. Ensure you provide as much information as possible on new question as well.